# How to link multiple CMake files together?

Tags: c, cmake, makefile, build, header

I am new at CMake and I really don't find any helpful tutorials. If you can recommend one, I would appreciate it.
I have a project with this structure:

```
project-dir
|- dir1
   |- c files (1.c)
   |- headers (1.h)
|- dir2
   |- dir3
      |- c files (3.c)
      |- headers (3.h)
   |- dir4
      |- c files (4.c)
      |- headers (4.h)
   |- c files (2.c)
   |- headers (2.h)
|- c files (pro.c)
|- headers (pro.h)
|- main.c
```

In every directory there is a CMakeList.txt like this:

```
set(DIR1 1.c 1.h)
add_library(dir1_lib ${DIR1})
```

In the project directory the cmake file is bigger:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(project_name VERSION 1.0 LANGUAGES C)

add_subdirectory(dir1)
add_subdirectory(dir2)

set(PRO
    pro.c
    pro.h
)

add_library(project_lib ${PRO})

include_directories(dir1)
include_directories(dir2)
include_directories(dir2/dir3)
include_directories(dir2/dir4)

add_executable(project_name main.c)

target_link_libraries(project_name dir1_lib)
target_link_libraries(project_name dir2_lib)
target_link_libraries(project_name dir3_lib)
target_link_libraries(project_name project_lib)
```

I would like to build the whole project as one but for instance the 3.c does not see the 2.h file. Like:

```
fatal error: 2.h: No such file or directory
```

The C and header files depends on each other like 3.h needs 2.h and 4.h needs 3.h and 1.h . I know it's so complicated but I'm sure there is a way to all the files sees each other. I tried to add include_directories() option to every CMake but it's not working.
That's how I tried:

```
set(DIR2 2.c 2.h)
add_library(dir2_lib ${DIR2})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir1)
include_directories(dir3)
include_directories(dir4)

#I added the subdirectory option too but still not working
add_subdirectory(dir3)
add_subdirectory(dir4)
```

I would like to build the whole project as one with multiple CMakes linked each other.

Comment: Do you get this error during build or during configure?

Comment: Your project structure looks a bit messed up. In dir2, you are also including header files of dir1, why? I suggest you first make a dependency tree on paper for this libraries.

Comment: Yes, I got this error: fatal error: 2.h: No such file or directory
Yeah, it's a little bit messed up but it's really hard to separate well the files. I'm going to try it with the dependency tree. Thank you for the idea!

Comment: The directory containing the header `2.h` is `dir2`. But in your `dir2/CMakeLists.txt` you include every other directory (`dir1`, `dir3`, `dir4`, but not `dir2`). Your calls to `include_directories` in main `CMakeLists.txt` don't affect on compiling `dir3_lib` library, because those calls comes **after** `add_subdirectory(dir2)`. You may specify corresponding `include_directories` in a single place - main `CMakeLists.txt` before the first `add_subdirectory`. But I agree with other commenters that your dependency tree is a mess.

Comment: I think Tsyvarev pretty much answered this question with his comment. I will only add to this with one more note: Understand that every CMakeLists has it's own **scope**. Just like in programming and you should remember to take that into account and treat CMake like every other language out there.